# How to Load picture from memory via boost.gil?

Tags: c++, image, boost, gil

Why gil removed the read_image (stream, ...) function

After the gil version 49d010ba6e83a64a249d00c934642334155593c2 will not ..

Comment: I don't recall that gil ever loaded images. I've always used [jpeglib](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) . I think it was in an old example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is in an extension:

https://github.com/boostorg/gil/blob/develop/include/boost/gil/extension/io/detail/read_image.hpp

See here for more background http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/gil/doc/html/gildesignguide.html#IO_DG